# Pytest missing approx method

Tags: python, pytest, attributeerror

I imported the pytest package in Python 3.5.2 (through Anaconda) and it is missing the approx method.  I tried reinstalling pytest through pip, and I still have the same problem.  I have many of pytest's other methods, just not approx.

How can I fix this??

```
      1 import pytest
----> 2 assert 2 == pytest.approx(4.1/2)

AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'approx'
```

Comment: Try importing it: `from pytest import approx`. Then write `assert 2 == approx(4.1/2)`.

Comment: What version of pytest is it? `import pytest ; print(pytest.__version__)`

Comment: It was a version issue!  I thought I had at least version 3 but I was checking on the server vs. my local machine...thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried, `from _pytest.python import approx`? It works for me. If not, you can search easily with IDE. I am using PyCharm, and I just searched the word `approx` by double shift and got the location.
Simple !!

Comment: @PierredeBuyl"The function should be available as requested" Yeah it should be. But here, it is not. You can not state it good or bad. It's about having solution with whatever version of pytest you have.

Comment: Here, the user probably needs to update. When something does not work as expected, I consider it more useful to look in the documentation how it should work and use this as a starting point.